# Converting numbers to K/M/G/T and days/hours/min?

Tags: perl

Is there an easy way to convert numbers like these

```
123           ->   123B
1234          ->   1.2K
12345         ->  12.2K
123456        -> 123.4K
1234567       ->   1.2M
12345678      ->  12.3M
123456789     -> 123.4M
...
```

and ideally also large numbers into days/hours/min. ?

Comment: `format_bytes` in [Number::Format](http://p3rl.org/Number::Format), [Number::Bytes::Human](http://p3rl.org/Number::Bytes::Human); [DateTime::Format::Duration](http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::Duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was discussed [on Stackoverflow using Time::Piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619236/difference-of-time-between-two-lines-of-a-log-file/8619447#8619447). One of the answers comes close to calculating days hours minutes. From what I've read about this question before, I think you can easily code it up like this:

```
sub dhms {
    my $seconds = shift;
    my $days = int $seconds / 86400;
    $seconds %= 86400;
    my $hours = int $seconds / 3600;
    $seconds %= 3600;
    my $mins = int $seconds / 60;
    my $secs = $seconds % 60;
    return $days, $hours, $mins, $secs;
}
```

Update: daxim's answer using DateTime::Format::Duration does this as well

Answer (score 1):

Suffixing is quite simple actually, once we understand the relationship between the letters *K, M, G, T* and the factors they present:

```
K = 10^3  = 10^3^1
M = 10^6  = 10^3^2
G = 10^9  = 10^3^3
T = 10^12 = 10^3^4
```

The next important thing to realize is that `10^0 = 1`.

We want to select the largest suffix whose value is smaller than the value we want to transform. To do that, we put the suffixes into an array:

```
my @suffixes = qw/ B K M G T /;
```

so that

```
$suffixes[$i] == 10**3**$i   # conceptually
```

Now it's just a matter of looping over the indices (probably in `reverse`) and stopping as soon as the `$val >= 10**3**$i`.