# Perl increment time starting from 00:00

Tags: perl, datetime-format

I want to generate an array of times in the format hh:mm given an interval and number of time points, starting at zero.  So, 3 time points of 10 minutes would yield (00:00, 00:10, 00:20).   I found this very nice snippet for incrementing and formatting the time an hour from now:

```
perl -e '@d=localtime time() + 600 - localtime time(); 
printf "%02d:%02d%s\n",$d[2]%12,$d[1]'
```

How can I replace "now" with "00:00"?  Bonus points for using the basic Perl modules.

Thanks,
L.

Comment: Wherever you found that snippet, you should put it back.

Comment: Now is a data and time. It can't be replaced with just a time. You need a date too, because not all days of all time zones have a 1:10, or even a 0:10. Do you want to use today's date?

Comment: You might be able to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112977/converting-numbers-to-k-m-g-t-and-days-hours-min/17115544#17115544) as a piece to solve your problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is simple enough; here's a function that takes two arguments, an interval length in minutes and a number of intervals to return, and returns an arrayref containing the specified intervals, expressed in your desired time format:

```
sub intervals {
    my $interval = shift(); # interval length in minutes
    my $n_points = shift(); # number of intervals to return
    die "intervals() takes two arguments\n"
            unless $interval and $n_points;

    my @now_tm = localtime();

    # check DST delta per @ikegami
    my $dst_delta = 0;
    my @yesterday_tm = localtime(time() - 86400);
    if ($yesterday_tm[8] && !$now_tm[8]) {
            # "fall back" - today is an hour shorter
            $dst_delta = -3600;
    }
    elsif (!$yesterday_tm[8] && $now_tm[8]) {
            # "spring forward" - today is an hour longer
            $dst_delta = 3600;
    };

    # find timestamp for 00:00 today
    my $now_ts = time();
    my $then_ts = $now_ts
            + $dst_delta          # apply any dst correction required 
            - ($now_tm[2] * 3600) # subtract hours since midnight
            - ($now_tm[1] * 60)   # ...and minutes
            - $now_tm[0];         # ...and seconds

    # generate actual intervals, starting at midnight
    my @interval_times = ();
    for (my $point = 0; $point < $n_points; $point++) {
            my $interval_ts = $then_ts + (($interval * 60) * $point);
            my @interval_tm = localtime($interval_ts);
            my $interval_formatted = sprintf("%0.2d:%0.2d", 
                                             $interval_tm[2],
                                             $interval_tm[1]);
            push @interval_times, $interval_formatted;
    };

    return [@interval_times];
};
```

Called as `intervals(10, 20)`, it returns the following:

```
0  ARRAY(0xd284e40)
   0  '00:00'
   1  '00:10'
   2  '00:20'
   3  '00:30'
   4  '00:40'
   5  '00:50'
   6  '01:00'
   7  '01:10'
   8  '01:20'
   9  '01:30'
   10  '01:40'
   11  '01:50'
   12  '02:00'
   13  '02:10'
   14  '02:20'
   15  '02:30'
   16  '02:40'
   17  '02:50'
   18  '03:00'
   19  '03:10'
```

And no Perl modules required, whether core or otherwise.

Comment: Your code fails for certain days of the year because of hours skipped or inserted due to DST. `$now_tm[2]` is not the number of hours since midnight.

Comment: @ikegami An excellent point; I've modified the function to handle that corner case. (At least in the US, DST corrections are inserted at 0200, which should I think mean that `(time() - 86400)` always ends up in yesterday, even on the "fall back" day that's 23 hours long. Correction of the algorithm, for regions where `(time() - 86400)` cannot be relied upon always to end up at some point in yesterday, is left as an exercise for the interested reader.)

Comment: Aaron: It says not to say thank-you but I really appreciate that code!

Comment: @LKramer Glad to be of help! Be warned, though, I haven't actually tested the DST correction, so you'll want to poke at that some before you put this into anything like production -- in particular, I suspect I may have the DST delta's sign reversed.